# Intellij - Generating Java Code from XML schema using XMLBeans

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a WSDL from which I am generating Java bean code.  It is storing it in a default jar named types.jar.  So far, so good.  But my classes that depend on the generated code can't seem to find it, so my code won't compile.

I tried adding the jar to the "module dependencies", but it still doesn't seem to recognize it.

Can someone tell me what step I missed?

Comment: Module dependencies should work, verify that you can browse to the missing classes in the Project View, Libraries node. See also http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html.

Comment: This is a maven project.  Do you mean the node that says "External Libraries"?

Comment: Yes, External Libraries.